# Ruby on Rails: Calling helper functions in controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can we call helper functions in controller methods? Can you give me a simple example too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just include the helper in the controller:

```
def MyController < ApplicationController
  include MyHelper
  ...
end
```